Update Angular 18 issue
I'm migrating an Ionic Angular Project to Angular 18.
After I updated the packages I got the following Errors:
Error:
1. If 'ion-searchbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-searchbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

4         <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="searchData($event)" color="light" debounce="500"></ion-searchbar>

  src/app/modals/searchable-adress-modal-component/searchable-adress-modal-component.component.ts:7:18
    7     templateUrl: './searchable-adress-modal-component.component.html',
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SearchableAdressModalComponentComponent.


Error: src/app/modals/searchable-adress-modal-component/searchable-adress-modal-component.component.html:5:9 - error NG8001: 'ion-spinner' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-spinner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-spinner' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

5         <ion-spinner *ngIf="loadDataSpinner" class="w-full justify-center mt-3 mb-3" color="primary"
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6 name="lines-sharp"></ion-spinner>
  src/app/modals/searchable-adress-modal-component/searchable-adress-modal-component.component.ts:7:18
    7     templateUrl: './searchable-adress-modal-component.component.html',
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SearchableAdressModalComponentComponent.

Ionic Module is imported in App.Module.ts
@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
imports: [        IonicModule.forRoot({
            scrollPadding: true,
            scrollAssist: true
        }),...],
providers: []
    providers: [
        {
            provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
            useClass: IonicRouteStrategy
        },
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            // Attach the Sentry ErrorHandler
            useValue: SentryAngular.createErrorHandler()
        },
        {
            provide: SentryAngular.TraceService,
            deps: [Router]
        },
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: () => () => {},
            deps: [TraceService],
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
}

So my modules are not importing correctly. I have Angular version 18.2.7 installed with ionic/angular v8.3.2
I'm struggling with that for hours. I tried to reinstall a couple of times, and took a look at the changeling but no hints for that.

Check whether searchable-adress-modal-component.component.ts component is
converted automatically to a standalone component or not
while upgrading to Angular 18
If it is converted, then in the component TS file, import IonicModule from '@ionic/angular'.
e.g.
@Component({
....
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule],
....
})

Standalone components specify their dependencies directly
instead of getting them through NgModules.

It helped on the Modal Components but I still get Errors on app.component.ts , there is also an app.module.ts defined and AppComponent is not an Standalone Component

Request you to provide latest error stack trace for AppComponent.
Ping @Component metadata for AppComponent and SearchableAdressModalComponent.
Below thread might help with standalone and non-standalone component mixture.
standalone and non-standalone component mixture thread
